# ThreeJs THREE.Mesh.position issue

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm totally new to three.js and just trying to get a grip on the three.js libraries.
I've got a sphere rendering to screen but I can't tell what it's .position member is referencing, it doesn't appear to be screen coordinates.
It's x0 point seems to be about half way across the screen (which i can handle and understand)
but it's y0 is roughly 1/3 up from the bottom of the screen and if I move it say 300 it's not moving by 300 pixels.

I'm kinda outta my depth and just hacking away at someone's example code to try and get a grip but this is bluffing me. I've tried looking over 3js API but not finding any answers.

I'll post the relevant code in case somethings wrong in there.

```
    <script src="js/Three.js"></script>
    <script src="js/Stats.js"></script>
    <script src="js/mDetector.js"></script>
    <script src="moddShape.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
        var SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
        var container,stats;
        var camera, scene;
        var canvasRenderer, webglRenderer;
        var mesh, zmesh, geometry, pointLight, pmesh, sphere, sphereMaterial;
        var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;
        var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
        var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
        var render_canvas = 1; 
        var render_gl = 1;
        var has_gl = 0;
        var targetX = 0, targetY = 0;
        var CameraZPos = 240;

        document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
        document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', handleMouseEvent, false );

        init();
        animate();

        function init() 
        {
            container = document.createElement( 'div' );
            document.body.appendChild( container );
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 90, SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, 1, 100000 );
            camera.position.z = CameraZPos;
            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            // RENDERER
            webglRenderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer
            (
                {
                    antialias: true
                }
            );
                webglRenderer.setSize( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT );
                webglRenderer.domElement.style.position = 'relative';
                container.appendChild( webglRenderer.domElement );
                has_gl = 1;

            // STATS - FPS
            stats = new Stats();
            stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
            stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';
            stats.domElement.style.left = '0px';
            stats.domElement.style.zIndex = 0;
            container.appendChild( stats.domElement );

            { 
                createScene(0, 100, 5, 0 ) 
            };

            // LIGHT
            var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight( 0xFFFFFF );
            // set its position
            pointLight.position.x = 10;
            pointLight.position.y = 50;
            pointLight.position.z = 130;
            // add to the scene
            scene.add(pointLight);
        }

        function createScene(x, y, z, b ) 
        {
            // create the sphere's material
            sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial(
            {
                // red.
                color: 0xCC0000
            });
            // set up the sphere vars
            var radius = 50, segments = 16, rings = 16;
            // create a new mesh with sphere geometry -
            sphere = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius, segments, rings), sphereMaterial);
            sphere.position.set( x, y, z ); 
            sphere.scale.set( 1, 1, 1 );
            sphere.overdraw = true;
            // add the sphere to the scene
            scene.add(sphere);
        }

        function onDocumentMouseMove(event) 
        {
            mouseX = ( event.clientX - windowHalfX );
            mouseY = ( event.clientY - windowHalfY );
        }

        function animate() 
        {
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            render();
            stats.update();//Update FPS
        }

        function handleMouseEvent(mouseEvent) 
        {
            targetX = mouseX;
            targetY = mouseY;
            //Text field printouts
            //Positions relevent to 0 0 midscreen
            document.myform.XY_Coords.value = "X Pos " + targetX + "\n" + "Y Pos " + targetY;
            //Positions relevent to 0 0 top left
            document.myform.XY_Coords.value += "\n\nX Pos 2 " + mouseEvent.clientX + "\n" + "Y Pos 2 " + mouseEvent.clientY;

        } 

        function render() 
        {
            if (sphere.position.x < targetX)
            {
                sphere.position.x += .1;
            }
            if (sphere.position.y < targetY)
            {
                sphere.position.y += .1;
            }
            if (sphere.position.x > targetX)
            {
                sphere.position.x -= .1;
            }
            if (sphere.position.y > targetY)
            {
                sphere.position.y -= .1;
            }               
            camera.lookAt( scene.position );
            document.myform.shipCoords.value = "ShipX " + sphere.position.x + "\nShipY " + sphere.position.y + "\nShipZ " + sphere.position.z;
            if ( render_gl && has_gl ) webglRenderer.render( scene, camera );
        }
    </script>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coordinates are not expressed using pixels. They are a more generic type of "units". I think you would like to read a bit more about WebGL (and 3D basics) to better understand and use Three.js.

Using that perspective camera you can center the sphere using:

```
createScene(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

You also need to change the sign (direction) of your y axis increments. `sphere.position.y += .1;` must be `sphere.position.y -= .1;` and `...-= 1;` must be `...+= 1;`

Comment: Hmmm, ok, but aren't the coordinates based on the screen resolution? Anyway I will be doing more reading. Do you know why (when I do use "CreateScene(0,0,0,0)" the sphere starts at about  y=200 (based on 0.0 being screen centre and not top left)? 
I'd put it down to camera position and or perspective but the camera seems to be centred? 
Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Julz **1)** Objects use world coordinates. Object transformations (translation, rotation, scalation), camera parameters (type, position, lookat, field of view, aspect ratio, min depth, max depth) and viewport definition (width, height) are used to get final screen coordinates. **2)** 200? Check a modified version of your code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HXqES/) Sphere seems to be centered.

Comment: I'm an idiot (probably goes without saying), it was the table at the top of the display throwing it out.
Thanks so much for your help.